# How to translate this Mongodb clause into mongoengine clause?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

```
db.students.find( { grades: { $elemMatch: {
                                            mean: { $gt: 70 },
                                            grade: { $gt:90 }
                                          } } },
                  { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

this is on official mongodb document, I have troubling translate them into mongoengine clause.

Can anybody translate this mongodb clause into mongoengine clause?

Because I have a embedded document in an array, I need to filter something inside the embedded document, I found this on the document, but don't know the exactly way to translate it. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, but I do it another way around, I implement elasticsearch into my mongodb to be the search engine, so that's not the problem